# How to wrap inputs within SelectInput from shiny using html?

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I am using a selectinput within Shiny R, to allow the user to select multiple input items. However, the items that I have are too long and as a result get cut off due to the size of the box I set (i.e. 400px). I am trying to use html code to alter the names by wrapping the words so that if the input item is longer than the width of the box, it will wrap to the next line. However, I am getting no change with the addition of the HTML tag. Any suggestions?

```
 selectInput( paste0("siFactors_",i), 
 choices = theCatFactorNameList, selectize=FALSE, multiple = TRUE, width = 400),  
 tags$head( tags$style(HTML(paste0(paste0(".siFactors_", i),  "{ word-wrap: break-word}")))
 )
```

Comment: I have an updated version of the tag$head line:                             tags$head( tags$style(type = "text/css",   " select.shiny-bound-input  { font-size:15px; height:200px; word-wrap: break-word}") )     This line allows me to edit the size of the text in select input, however the word-wrap function does not work.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
  tags$style(    type='text/css', 
                 ".selectize-input { word-wrap: break-word;}"
                  )
```